# How to send data from local storage to a SQL database from a button click in a Blazor app

Tags: c#, sql, razor, blazor

I'm currently developing a Blazor application for electronic recycling. The app allows employees to input information into a form, and all the entered data is stored in local storage. After inputting the data, users are redirected to a summary page where they can confirm the accuracy of the entered information.

The current functionality is working well, but I'm facing a challenge with the submit button. I want the app to perform the following actions upon submission:

Check the database to see if the `CPSNumber` already exists.

- If the `CPSNumber` is found, update the corresponding columns in the database with the information from the form.
- If the `CPSNumber` is not found, add the columns from the summary page to the database.

Could you provide guidance or code snippets on how to implement this logic in my Blazor app?

EDIT Here is the code for the form the employees fill out:

```
@page "/form"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using System.Text.Json;
@using Blazored.LocalStorage;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService oLocalStore


<PageTitle>Form</PageTitle>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="h3" style="display: block; text-align: center">Welcome Chris DeBrodie!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
             @foreach (var (inputData, index) in inputCardData.Select((data, index) => (data, index)))
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if (index == 0)
        {
            <!-- Render the dropdown only for the first card -->
            <RadzenDropDown TValue="string" ValueProperty="BuildingName" TextProperty="BuildingName" Data="@buildingLists" @bind-Value="inputData.BuildingName"  AllowSelectAll="false" Placeholder="School Name" Style="width: 100%; text-align: center" />
        }
        
        <RadzenCard Variant="Radzen.Variant.Filled">
            <div class="form-group">
                <RadzenAutoComplete TextProperty="CPSNumber" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.CPSNumber" Placeholder="CPS Number" Style="width: 100%; text-align: left" @oninput="() => AddNewCard(index)" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <RadzenAutoComplete TextProperty="Description" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.Description" Placeholder="Item Description" Style="width: 100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            </div>
            <RadzenDropDown TValue="string" ValueProperty="ReasonDescription" TextProperty="ReasonDescription" Data="@reasons" @bind-Value="inputData.ReasonDescription" Placeholder="Reason For Surplus" Style="width: 100%" />
        </RadzenCard>
    </div>
}



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Review" Click="FinalizeList"></RadzenButton>



@code {
    [Inject]
    protected Surplus.WASPOService WASPOService { get; set; }

    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> surplusItemsNews;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> buildingLists;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason> reasons;

    // Create a class to hold form data
    public class FormData
    {
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
    }
    

    // Inject the ILocalStorageService
    [Inject]
    private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }

    // Create a list to store instances of the form data
    List<FormData> inputCardData;

    

    // Constructor to initialize inputCardData
    public Form()
    {
        inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
        // Add a default instance to the list
        inputCardData.Add(new FormData());
    }










    private int cardIdCounter = 1;

    [Inject]
    protected SecurityService Security { get; set; } // Counter for the card ID

// Event handler for adding a new card when a ReasonDescription is selected
private void AddNewCard(int index)
{
    // Check if the current card is the last one in the list
    if (index == inputCardData.Count - 1)
    {
        // Add a new FormData instance without copying the BuildingName property
        inputCardData.Add(new FormData
        {   
            CPSNumber = inputCardData[index].CPSNumber,
            Description = inputCardData[index].Description,
            ReasonDescription = inputCardData[index].ReasonDescription
            
        });

        cardIdCounter++; // Increase the ID counter
    }
}


    // Function to save inputCardData to local storage
    private async Task SaveInputCardDataToLocalStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("inputCardData", inputCardData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving to local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // Function to load inputCardData from local storage
    private async Task LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            inputCardData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");
            // Initialize the list if it's null
            if (inputCardData == null)
            {
                inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
                //Initialize list with Default instance of FormData when nothing is stored in local storage
                FormData defaultFormData = new FormData();
                inputCardData.Add(defaultFormData);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        surplusItemsNews = await WASPOService.GetSurplusItemsNews();
        buildingLists = await WASPOService.GetBuildingLists();
        reasons = await WASPOService.GetReasons();

        // Load inputCardData from local storage when the page initializes
        await LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage();
    }

    // Event handler for the "Finalize List" button
// Event handler for the "Finalize List" button

    // Event handler for the "Finalize List" button
    private async Task FinalizeList()
    {
        // Save the input card data to local storage
        await SaveInputCardDataToLocalStorage();

        // Navigate to the summary page
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/summary");
    }

}
```

EDIT Here is my UPDATED  summary code:

```
   @page "/summary"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using System.Text.Json;
@inject IJSRuntime _js
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
@inject CSPNumerManager CspNumberService

<PageTitle>Summary</PageTitle>

<RadzenGrid Data="@filteredSessionData" TItem="FormData">

    <Columns>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="BuildingName" Title="School" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="CPSNumber" Title="CPS Number" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="Description" Title="Item Description" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="ReasonDescription" Title="Reason For Surplus" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="Edit">
            <Template Context="data">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" Style="background-color: #005570;" Click="() => EditItem(data)"></RadzenButton>
                </div>
            </Template>
        </RadzenGridColumn>
    </Columns>
</RadzenGrid>
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Submit" @onclick="async () => await YourSaveFunction()"></RadzenButton>
<div class="back-button">
    <RadzenButton Icon="print" Style="background-color: #005570; float: left; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: center" Click="PrintMe"></RadzenButton>
</div>

@code {





    private async Task PrintMe()
        => await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.print");
    // Define the FormData class if it's not already defined
    public class FormData
    {
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
        public int SurplusStatus { get; set; }
    }



    // Read the stored local storage data
    private List<FormData> sessionData = new List<FormData>();

    // Filtered session data without null CPSNumber
    private List<FormData> filteredSessionData = new List<FormData>();

    // Inject the ILocalStorageService
    [Inject]
    private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected SecurityService Security { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Load the data from local storage
        try
        {
            sessionData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");

            // Filter out rows with null CPSNumber
            filteredSessionData = sessionData.Where(row => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.CPSNumber)).ToList();

            // Set the same BuildingName for all rows
            if (filteredSessionData.Count > 0)
            {
                var buildingName = filteredSessionData[0].BuildingName;
                filteredSessionData.ForEach(row => row.BuildingName = buildingName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void EditItem(FormData data)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Form"); // Replace with the actual Razor page URL
    }


    private async Task YourSaveFunction()
    {
        await CspNumberService.SaveUserData();

        // Display a success message or perform other actions
        NotificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Success, "Data submitted successfully");
    }


}




<style>
    .back-button {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
    }

    .back-button a {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #005570;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .back-icon {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

EDIT Here is my CSPNumerManager class code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Surplus;
using Surplus.Data;
using static Surplus.Pages.Summary;

public class CSPNumerManager
{
    private readonly WASPOService _waspoService;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

    public CSPNumerManager(WASPOService waspoService, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        _waspoService = waspoService;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveUserData()
    {
        var dataToSend = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");

        // Check each CPSNumber against the database
        foreach (var formData in dataToSend)
        {
            _waspoService.UpdateOrAddFormData(new List<FormData> { formData });
        }

        return true; // You might want to enhance this logic based on your requirements
    }
}
```

here is my service code Please look at the PLEASE LOOK HERE COMMENT IN THIS CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Radzen;

using Surplus.Data;
using static Surplus.Pages.Summary;
using Surplus.Pages;

namespace Surplus
{
    public partial class WASPOService
    {
        WASPOContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                return this.context;
            }
        }

        private readonly WASPOContext context;
        private readonly NavigationManager navigationManager;

        public WASPOService(WASPOContext context, NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.navigationManager = navigationManager;
        }

        public void Reset() => Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);

        public void ApplyQuery<T>(ref IQueryable<T> items, Query query = null)
        {
            if (query != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Filter))
                {
                    if (query.FilterParameters != null)
                    {
                        items = items.Where(query.Filter, query.FilterParameters);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items = items.Where(query.Filter);
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.OrderBy))
                {
                    items = items.OrderBy(query.OrderBy);
                }

                if (query.Skip.HasValue)
                {
                    items = items.Skip(query.Skip.Value);
                }

                if (query.Top.HasValue)
                {
                    items = items.Take(query.Top.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task ExportReasonsToExcel(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/waspo/reasons/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/waspo/reasons/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        public async Task ExportReasonsToCSV(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/waspo/reasons/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/waspo/reasons/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        partial void OnReasonsRead(ref IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason> items);

        public async Task<IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason>> GetReasons(Query query = null)
        {
            var items = Context.Reasons.AsQueryable();

            if (query != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Expand))
                {
                    var propertiesToExpand = query.Expand.Split(',');
                    foreach (var p in propertiesToExpand)
                    {
                        items = items.Include(p.Trim());
                    }
                }

                ApplyQuery(ref items, query);
            }

            OnReasonsRead(ref items);

            return await Task.FromResult(items);
        }

        public async Task ExportBuildingListsToExcel(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/waspo/buildinglists/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/waspo/buildinglists/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        public async Task ExportBuildingListsToCSV(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/waspo/buildinglists/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/waspo/buildinglists/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        partial void OnBuildingListsRead(ref IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> items);

        public async Task<IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList>> GetBuildingLists(Query query = null)
        {
            var items = Context.BuildingLists.AsQueryable();

            if (query != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Expand))
                {
                    var propertiesToExpand = query.Expand.Split(',');
                    foreach (var p in propertiesToExpand)
                    {
                        items = items.Include(p.Trim());
                    }
                }

                ApplyQuery(ref items, query);
            }

            OnBuildingListsRead(ref items);

            return await Task.FromResult(items);
        }

        public async Task ExportSurplusItemsNewsToExcel(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/waspo/surplusitemsnews/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/waspo/surplusitemsnews/excel(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        public async Task ExportSurplusItemsNewsToCSV(Query query = null, string fileName = null)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo(query != null ? query.ToUrl($"export/waspo/surplusitemsnews/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')") : $"export/waspo/surplusitemsnews/csv(fileName='{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(fileName) : "Export")}')", true);
        }

        partial void OnSurplusItemsNewsRead(ref IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> items);

        public async Task<IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew>> GetSurplusItemsNews(Query query = null)
        {
            var items = Context.SurplusItemsNews.AsQueryable();

            if (query != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Expand))
                {
                    var propertiesToExpand = query.Expand.Split(',');
                    foreach (var p in propertiesToExpand)
                    {
                        items = items.Include(p.Trim());
                    }
                }

                ApplyQuery(ref items, query);
            }

            OnSurplusItemsNewsRead(ref items);

            return await Task.FromResult(items);
        }



        // New method for updating or adding FormData

        //PLEASE LOOK AT THIS CODE HERE!!!!
        public void UpdateOrAddFormData(List<FormData> formDataList)
        {
            foreach (var formData in formDataList)
            {
                // Issue with AsQueryable
                var existingData = ((IEnumerable<FormData>)Context.FormData).AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(fd => fd.CPSNumber == formData.CPSNumber);

                if (existingData != null)
                {
                    // Update existing row in the database
                    existingData.BuildingName = formData.BuildingName;
                    existingData.Description = formData.Description;
                    existingData.ReasonDescription = formData.ReasonDescription;
                    existingData.SurplusStatus = 1; // Set SurplusStatus to 1
                }
                else
                {
                    // Issue with ToList
                    var formDataListCollection = ((IEnumerable<FormData>)Context.FormData).ToList();

                    // Add new row to the database
                    formData.SurplusStatus = 1; // Set SurplusStatus to 1 for new row
                    formDataListCollection.Add(formData);
                }
            }

            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**However when I click the submit button the data in formlist is not being inserted/updated in the database**

UPDATE: what I see when I click the submit button in the debugger:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Hosting environment: Development
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Content root path: D:\Apps\CPS Surplus\CPS Surplus\
    info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
          Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'WASPOContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0' with options: None
    info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT [b].[BuildingID], [b].[BuildingLink], [b].[BuildingName], [b].[BuildingSubFlag], [b].[DESENo], [b].[LocCode]
          FROM [dbo].[BuildingList] AS [b]
    info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
          Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue was in my submit button code it needed to be

```
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Submit"  Click="YourSaveFunction"></RadzenButton>
```

**NOT**

```
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Submit" @onclick="async () => await YourSaveFunction()"></RadzenButton>
```

The button was never registering the click..... changed that and it worked like a charm!!!!!!!!!!!

thank you to everyone who helped out on this post!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add something to the db, the best way to do that is to call the backend and send data for your action, and then in action, WHERE EXISTS update and else create new
applications designed as backendless so they can call db directly from client. but in your case, you should send data for the backend and Put the responsibility on them.

Comment: thank you for the reply do you have any links or  code samples you can provide for your suggestion? thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to manage your app state depending on the DB state. I assume you use Blazor Server/ ServerRendering (If not you have to make it more precise in question.)

First of I would make new class .cs named for example CSPNumerManager.
Then you have to add it to DI like this :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CSPNumerManager>(); //Scoped for current user in Server mode
```

In CSPNumberManager you can inject your services and storage like in your component but using constructor. (You can also store the data there in variables if they do not have to be long lived.)

In component you just add:

```
@inject CSPNumerManager CspNumberService

//Add button like this:

<button type="button" @onclick="YourSaveFunction"> Save <button/>

//Then add this function:

private async Task YourSaveFunction()
{
  await CspNumberService.SaveUserData();
}
```

Also you can add other method as you like. As for class I would do like this:

```
public class CSPNumerManager 
{
   IYourDbOrApplicationLogicService a1 {get;set;}
   IYourLocalStorageService a2 {get;set;}

   public CSPNumerManager ( // Inject your services //)
   {
    //Inject your services
   }

   public async Task<bool> SaveUserData()
   {
    var dataToSend  = await a2.GetUserData(); // Get data from local storage or any other place. IYourLocalStorageService  could be custom Storage service or protected storage
    bool IsSuccess=  a1.SendDataToApplicationOrDataBaseOrApiWithYourData(dataToSend ) ;

    return IsSuccess; 
   }

}
```

As what your do further in you DB logic class does not concern blazor. I really do not see where difficulty is. IYourDbOrApplicationLogicService  you can implement any class with your custom DB logic. In there you can use dapper or any other library.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am still having issues please see updated code and question thanks!!!

Comment: As for the errors, you do not have SaveChangesAsync you have SaveChanges in your service.  You have a little messy code.  I would personally remove functions from razor component such as  CheckIfCPSNumberExists, DatabaseContainsCPSNumber Etc.    Just in submit function create DTO from your data and pass it to your service. There in a function in your service  check conditions and use your DbContext. You can use normal html button with @onclick, no need for fancy stuff also.  I see many content is AI generated. Stay simple and you do not need to use 3rd party libs for simple visual stuff.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help so far!!! I did your suggestion but the data is not inserting /updating to my sql database please see my updated code in the edits in the question!!! Thanks :)

Comment: The code now looks so much nicer. Before I go to Query stuff I have other questions. Where are you adding "inputCardData", I do not see SetAsync anywhere, are you saving your data anywhere ? .  In your YourSaveFunction you should be passing an argument of FormData (data that you want to add), form data can be populated from other form. In SaveUserData I would send to DB only data that you want to add (your missing FormData ) not whole list. DB function should return status of operation. Based on that you get your "inputCardData", and then add or replace given row using _localStorage.SetAsync()

Comment: thank you very much!!!! and the inputCardData is on the actual form page that the employees fill out that gets saved into localstorage and then gets loaded on the summary page from localstorage. I have added that code to the edited question please let me know if you have any other questions and thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: did you see my last comment/update by chance?

Comment: I'm sorry ,I'm busy lately. First off, why in your EF saving function, you are not doing simply  Context.FormData.Add(formData) for new elements ? I would move all stuff related for getting and setting storage for your form data into CSPNumerManager (single responsibility). You should have two methods SaveUserData(List<FormData>) and GetUserData. Then Localstorage stuff will be in one place. Your UpdateOrAddFormData should return class/variable that indicates if operation was success. Lastly there are to many dependencies for me to run the code, so you must tell us what debugger sees.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!!! I have updated the question with what I see in the debugger please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Sorry, with debugger I meant did you saw what values are being pulled from local store and send to DB. Also you have not done/answered other suggestion. I feel like there is not much more that can be helped with current limited information .

Comment: I got it to work! please see accepted answer thank you to @everyone who helped out with this issue :)